# Why would exporting an eclipse RCP product hang?

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I am building Mac and Win versions of an RCP product using Eclipse 3.5.1. I've installed the RCP delta pack and everything looks great. However, when I go to export, the progress bar gets stuck at "Publishing Metadata" (about 20% through the export process). It never makes any progress after that. Further, cancelling has no effect at all. I have to kill Eclipse to end it.

The workspace .metadata/.log file has no warnings at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: How long are you waiting before declaring it dead?

Comment: 5 minutes. I had this flow working a few months ago on an older eclipse version and the export took 30 seconds or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this (for me) seems to be to make a new .product file using the new version of Eclipse. As soon as I did this all was well. Thanks to anyone who gave it some thought.

Per the commenter's great suggestion I went to bugs.eclipse.org and found [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=276005) which is the source of my hang

Comment: If you still have the old .product file and can still reproduce the hang, it would be worth trying to get a stack trace: http://wiki.eclipse.org/How_to_report_a_deadlock.  You could attach it to a new bug against PDE/Build https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=PDE

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall having this problem, but only intermittently (and I think on an older version of Eclipse). I never really found the cause, but I suspected a memory leak as it seemed more likely to happen the longer I had Eclipse open, ie. it used to happen after I'd done several successful exports.

My "solution" was to re-start Eclipse, prior to an export. From memory it always solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A p2 repository is exported by default, so watch for that.  With p2, it takes 3-4 minutes (I though I was hung) to export my plugin and without it exports in 1-2 seconds.  If you don't need p2, turn it off.

Comment: I'm assuming you're exporting a product.  See http://www.andyczerwonka.com/p2.png

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch off generate metadata checkbox in export dialog